# How to add annotations in pgf sequencediagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, annotations

How can we add annotations in sequencediagrams?
I want to add annotations (depicting some functionality) at the return of each response (on receiving ARes, BRes, CRes). How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[underline=true]{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread {r}    {R} {}
    \newinst [1] {a} {A}
    \newinst [1] {e} {E}
    \newinst [1] {u} {U}
    
        \begin {sdblock} {Block} {}
        \path (inst1.west) -- (inst4.east);
            \begin{call}{r}{ACall}{a}{ARes}
                \begin{call}{a}{B}{e}{BRes}
                    \begin{call}{e}{CCall}{u}{CRes}
                    \end{call}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end {sdblock}                                      
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package `pgf-umlsd` internally defines nodes `cfn`, `ctn`, `rfn` and `rtn` for call from/to and return from/to, for call number `n`. For example, the arrow labeled ACall in the code from the question goes from node `(cf1)` to `(ct1)`.

The node labels that you want to annotate do not have a name in `pgf-umlsd`, unfortunately. However, using the `calc` tikzlibrary you can define a node as the midway point between two nodes, in this case the from/to nodes. The syntax for this is `($(first node)!0.5!(second node)$)`.

To put the annotation below the arrow you can use the `.south` anchor for the nodes when calculating the midway point.

For some more control over the position of the annotation node you can use `xshift` and `yshift` or the fine-grained control of the `calc` library itself.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[underline=true]{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
    \newthread {r}    {R} {}
    \newinst [1] {a} {A}
    \newinst [1] {e} {E}
    \newinst [1] {u} {U}
    
        \begin {sdblock} {Block} {}
        \path (inst1.west) -- (inst4.east);
            \begin{call}{r}{ACall}{a}{ARes}
                \begin{call}{a}{B}{e}{BRes}
                    \begin{call}{e}{CCall}{u}{CRes}
                    \end{call}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end {sdblock}
        \node (aannot) at ($(rf1.south)!0.5!(rt1.south)$) {annot A};                                
        \node[yshift=-3mm] (bannot) at ($(rf2.south)!0.5!(rt2.south)$) {annot B};
    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]